# Не показывает ничего на эмуляторе во Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Код

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {

  var textDirection;
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: "Flutter tut",
      home: Text(
        "hi world",
        textDirection: textDirection.ltr,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Ошибка

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
Restarted application in 1 653ms.
E/flutter (10196): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'ltr' was called on null.
E/flutter (10196): Receiver: null
E/flutter (10196): Tried calling: ltr
E/flutter (10196): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:38:5)
E/flutter (10196): #1      main (package:tuto/main.dart:15:38)
E/flutter (10196): #2      _runMain.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:134:23)
E/flutter (10196): #3      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:297:19)
E/flutter (10196): #4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
E/flutter (10196):
```

В чём проблема?

Comment: В этом проблема `textDirection.ltr`

Comment: и как её решить ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: "Flutter tut",
      home: Text(
        "hi world",
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Убери объявление переменной. Зачем оно тут. Все же в ошибке написано.